# How to export type definitions and use them via npm link of a local package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, typescript-typings, npm-package

I'm creating a supertest alternative called [tepper](https://github.com/DanielRamosAcosta/tepper). I'm trying to publish the package both as ESM and CJS. The problem I'm having is that a consumer of the library isn't able to find the type definitions.

In order to test it, I've created a script (you can find it [here](https://github.com/DanielRamosAcosta/tepper/blob/fbec6cbdffe199f046e0b86b06765d3d5472c370/test/e2e/nestjs/run.sh)), that generates a brand-new NestJS project, and tries to use the library by installing it locally using a relative path (`npm install --save-dev ../../../..`)

The problem is that I'm having an `TS2307: Cannot find module 'tepper' or its corresponding type declarations` error ([here](https://github.com/DanielRamosAcosta/tepper/actions/runs/6537927339/job/17752768621) you can see the error on Github Actions).

I've exported the types in [package.json](https://github.com/DanielRamosAcosta/tepper/blob/fbec6cbdffe199f046e0b86b06765d3d5472c370/package.json) as I'm supposed:

```
{
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/types/tepper.d.ts",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/tepper.js",
      "import": "./dist/esm/tepper.js",
      "default": "./dist/esm/tepper.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend you to check if 1) you are building it before test 2) if resulting package.json actually contains tepper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is `resolvePackageJsonExports` in tsconfig. Refer to https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#resolvePackageJsonExports.

In your project, it is not enabled because of values of `moduleResolution` and `module`. So you have 2 options,

- 1. in file test/e2e/nestjs/project-name/tsconfig.json, setup following things.

```
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "resolvePackageJsonExports": true,
```

- 2. use the classic `types` field in tepper's main packages.json, which can avoid other things be affected due to changes of `moduleResolution` and `module`.

```
"types": "./dist/types/tepper.d.ts",
```

Comment: Note: When setting [`module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) to `NodeNext`, [`moduleResolution`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution) defaults to `NodeNext`, and when `moduleResolution` is `NodeNext`, [`resolvePackageJsonExports`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#resolvePackageJsonExports) defaults to `true`, so the only mandatory setting is `"module": "NodeNext"` unless others have been modified from defaults.